# C programming to make multiplication table (1-12)

Tags: c, formatting

I want to make a program that takes a single integer command line argument (n) and makes n x n multiplication table resembling the 4x4 example below. It should be only 1 through 12, but shouldn't be no smaller or larger. So if there is not enough argument, it should be print a usuage: `Usage: program <n> \n` or if it is out of range then it should be print: `n out of range (1-12)\n` and exit.

Example:
./program 4

```
*    1   2   3   4
  +----------------
 1|   1   2   3   4
 2|   2   4   6   8
 3|   3   6   9  12
 4|   4   8  12  16
```

My code I have tried but wasn't success. I have copied the compiled is not what I expected in the below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int i, j;

    printf(" +");
    for (i = 1; i < 13; ++i) 
    {
        printf("%#3d ", i);
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 1; i < 64; ++i) 
    {
        printf("-");
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 1; i < 13; ++i) 
    {
        printf("%#2d |", i);

        for (j = 1; j < 11; ++j) 
        {
            printf("%#3d ", i * j);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> After compile:
>
> ```
> gcc version 4.6.3
>
>  +  1 
>   2 
>   3 
>   4 
>   5 
>   6 
>   7 
>   8 
>   9 
>  10 
>  11 
>  12 
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
> -
>  1 |  1 
>   2 
>   3 
>   4 
>   5 
>   6 
>   7 
>   8 
>   9 
>  10 
>  2 |  2 
>   4 
>   6 
>   8 
>  10 
>  12 
>  14 
>  16 
>  18 
>  20 
>  3 |  3 
>   6 
>   9 
>  12 
>  15 
>  18 
>  21 
>  24 
>  27 
>  30 
>  4 |  4 
>   8 
>  12 
>  16 
>  20 
>  24 
>  28 
>  32 
>  36 
>  40 
>  5 |  5 
>  10 
>  15 
>  20 
>  25 
>  30 
>  35 
>  40 
>  45 
>  50 
>  6 |  6 
>  12 
>  18 
>  24 
>  30 
>  36 
>  42 
>  48 
>  54 
>  60 
>  7 |  7 
>  14 
>  21 
>  28 
>  35 
>  42 
>  49 
>  56 
>  63 
>  70 
>  8 |  8 
>  16 
>  24 
>  32 
>  40 
>  48 
>  56 
>  64 
>  72 
>  80 
>  9 |  9 
>  18 
>  27 
>  36 
>  45 
>  54 
>  63 
>  72 
>  81 
>  90 
> 10 | 10 
>  20 
>  30 
>  40 
>  50 
>  60 
>  70 
>  80 
>  90 
> 100 
> 11 | 11 
>  22 
>  33 
>  44 
>  55 
>  66 
>  77 
>  88 
>  99 
> 110 
> 12 | 12 
>  24 
>  36 
>  48 
>  60 
>  72 
>  84 
>  96 
> 108 
> 120
> ```

I have been stuck on this for 2 days and trying to figure it out why is it going straight down.. Thank you.

Comment: Ask yourself what does `printf ("\n");` do?

Comment: ...and equally important, *where* it's doing it.

Comment: It is new line but if I don't use those, it will looks messy. You can take look at it. https://repl.it/repls/HeartySandybrownTask

Comment: Who said anything about not using  them? The question was, *what* do they do, and *where* are they doing it? [Let me put that another way](https://repl.it/repls/StaidKindlyDesignmethod).

Comment: regarding these kinds of statements: `printf("%#3d ", i);`  The `#` should not be there.  Amongst other things, it causes the compiler to output a warning message.  Suggest removing the `#` from the format statements

Comment: regarding: `repl.it/repls/HeartySandybrownTask`   DO NOT post links to external web sites, they tend to move or disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code:

1. corrects the output formatting,
2. checks if there is a command line parameter,
3. follows the axiom:
   *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
4. checks the command line parameter to assure it is numeric and in the range 1...12
5. limits the `scope` of each variable
6. calls `puts()` where appropriate as `printf()` is very expensive in CPU cycles
7. uses appropriate horizontal spacing for readability

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <ctype.h>    // isdigit()

#define MAX_VALUE 12
#define MIN_VALUE 1

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
{

    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <maxTableSize: range 1...12>\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, user entered a command line parameter

    if( !isdigit( argv[1][0] ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "command line parameter not numeric\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, command line parameter starts with digit

    int maxTableSize = atoi( argv[1] );

    if( MIN_VALUE > maxTableSize || maxTableSize > MAX_VALUE )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "command line parameter not in valid range ( 1...12 )\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, command line parameter contains valid value

    printf(" +  ");
    for ( int i = 1; i <= maxTableSize; ++i ) 
    {
        printf("%4d ", i);
    }
    puts("");

    for ( int i = 1; i < 5+(maxTableSize*5); ++i ) 
    {
        printf( "-" );
    }
    puts("");

    for ( int i = 1; i <= maxTableSize; ++i ) 
    {
        printf( "%2d |", i );

        for ( int j = 1; j <= maxTableSize; ++j ) 
        {
            printf( "%4d ", i * j );
        }
        puts("");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the following demonstrates the various conditions of running the program. (where `untitled` is the name of the program.)

```
./untitled
USAGE: ./untitled <maxTableSize: range 1...12>

./untitled a
command line parameter not numeric

./untitled 0
command line parameter not in valid range ( 1...12 )

./untitled 13
command line parameter not in valid range ( 1...12 )


./untitled 1
 +     1 
--------
 1 |   1 

./untitled 2
 +     1    2 
------------
 1 |   1    2 
 2 |   2    4 

 .....

./untitled 12
 +     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12 
----------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12 
 2 |   2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20   22   24 
 3 |   3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30   33   36 
 4 |   4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40   44   48 
 5 |   5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50   55   60 
 6 |   6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54   60   66   72 
 7 |   7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63   70   77   84 
 8 |   8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   80   88   96 
 9 |   9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81   90   99  108 
10 |  10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100  110  120 
11 |  11   22   33   44   55   66   77   88   99  110  121  132 
12 |  12   24   36   48   60   72   84   96  108  120  132  144
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are making 2 mistakes.

1. You are adding the `printf ("\n")` inside the for loop. This should be outside the `for` loop in case of single loop. In case of nested loop, the new line should be after each internal `for` loop.
2. You are using `%#3d` in printf. The `#` should be removed.

Other than that, after making few changes in printf alignment, the updated code is below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int i, j;

    printf("   +");
    for (i = 1; i < 13; ++i) 
    {
        printf("%4d ", i);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 1; i < 64; ++i) 
    {
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 1; i < 13; ++i) 
    {
        printf("%2d |", i);

        for (j = 1; j < 13; ++j) 
        {
            printf("%4d ", i * j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> Output is as below

```
   +   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
---------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
 2 |   2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20   22   24
 3 |   3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30   33   36
 4 |   4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40   44   48
 5 |   5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50   55   60
 6 |   6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54   60   66   72
 7 |   7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63   70   77   84
 8 |   8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   80   88   96
 9 |   9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81   90   99  108
10 |  10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100  110  120
11 |  11   22   33   44   55   66   77   88   99  110  121  132
12 |  12   24   36   48   60   72   84   96  108  120  132  144
```